# Can anyone help with these integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$1.\int{x\over \sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}dx$$
$$2.\int{\sqrt{x+1}+2\over (x+1)^2- \sqrt{x+1}}dx$$
$$3.\int{\sqrt[3]{1-\sqrt[4]{x}}\over \sqrt{x}}dx$$

Just need the general idea, im not expecting someone to do each one individually in detail. For the first one i was thinking Euler's substitution in the case a>0. With the second im having trouble choosing a substitution, because of the different roots, also goes for the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one, $x=\sin\theta$ plus the sine duplication/bisection formulas.

For the second one, $x=z^2-1$.

For the third one, $x=(1-t^3)^{4}$.

Comment: @BozoVulicevic: You're welcome.

Comment: Did you make these conclusions intuitively or is there an algorithm to solving either of these integrals?

Comment: @BozoVulicevic: Many complex algorithms are implemented in Mathematica and in other CAS, but being on the human side an effective algorithm is: try to get rid of all the roots. If it doesn't seem to work, try the most natural (hyperbolic) trigonometric substitution.

Comment: can this be solved: $\int \sqrt{t^4-1}dt$ ?

Comment: i meant accually this one abovethis comment except it be a definite integral with some real interval as the lower and upper bound..

Comment: @BozoVulicevic: $\int\sqrt{t^4-1}\,dt$ depends on the elliptic integral of the first kind, hence it is not an elementary primitive, but the integral over some interval can be (very effectively) bounded by exploiting Taylor series and/or convexity arguments. The chinese mathematician Feng Qi mastered many extremely tight approximations for elliptic functions, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

In general if you have a radical mixed together with other stuff, it sometimes helps to "wish away" the most complicated radical.  In this case, letting $u=1-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ in 1), $u=\sqrt{x+1}$ in 2), and $u=1-\sqrt[4]x$ in 3) works wonders.

This "wishful thinking" doesn't always work, of course.  But it never hurts to try.